Galois Theory and the Rational Functions Field.

Problem. Let $F$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}(F)=3$. Define the following field $$E =\{f(t)\in F(t): f(t)=f(1-t)\}$$
which is a subfield of the rational functions field $F(t)$. Prove that $F(t)$ is Galois over $E$ and compute the Galois group.

This problem gives me a lot of trouble. I am trying to prove the normality from taking an $E$-morphism $h:F(t)\to\overline{E}$ and deduce that the image is $F(t)$ itself. Let $f(t)\in F(t)$ then $h(f(t))=f(h(t))$. So it suffices to show $h(t)\in F(t).$ This inspires me to compute the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $E$ and trying to come up with some special functions in $E$. I cannot come up with these kind of examples. I can only observe from the characteristic that $(1-t)^3=1-t^3$ so if $f(t)=t^3$ then $f(1-t)=1-f(t)$. Separability would give me more trouble since I am having trouble determining the minimal polynomial or even a nontrivial vanishing polynomial in $E[x]$.

Can you think of one automorphism of $F(t)$ that fixes $E?$

There is a classical theorem in Galois theory, which is usually used to prove the fundamental theorem: if $L$ is a field, $G\leq\text{Aut}(L)$ is a finite subgroup, and we denote the fixed field of $G$ by $L^G$, then $L/L^G$ is a Galois extension, and $\text{Gal}(L/L^G)=G$.
In our case, define $\sigma:F(t)\to F(t)$ by $\sigma(f(t))=f(1-t)$. This is clearly an automorphism of order $2$, and $E=F(t)^{\langle\sigma\rangle}$. So by the theorem, $F(t)/E$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $\langle\sigma\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
If you are not familiar with the theorem yet, and want some more direct solution, you can try to find the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $E$. Note that $t^2+(1-t)^2=2t^2-2t+1$ is an element of $E$, and $t$ is a root of:
$2T^2-2T+1-(t^2+(1-t)^2)\in E[T]$
Since $t\notin E$, this must be the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $E$, and so $[F(t):E]=2$. As $\sigma$ and the identity are two automorphisms of the extension, it follows that they must be all the automorphisms (the number is always bounded by the extension degree), and so this is a Galois extension with a Galois group of order $2$.
